# Understanding shifting and masking in opencl kernel

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

Consider the following kernel:

```
__kernel void histogramKernel(__global uint4 *Image,  ....)     
 {                         .
                     .
                     .
 const uint mask = (uint) (NBINS-1);  //NBINS=256
 uint4 temp = Image[idx];   
 uint4 temp2 = (temp & mask);
 temp = temp >> 8;
 temp2 = (temp & mask);
 . . .

 }
```

Suppose:

4 threads are running, idx=0,1,2,3 and
 Image[idx]=idx+100

What will be the value in temp2 in the last line?

**Update:**

Assume any suitable values for

```
 Image[0].x, Image[0].y, Image[0].z, Image[0].w
 Image[1].x, Image[1].y, Image[1].z, Image[1].w
 Image[2].x, Image[2].y, Image[2].z, Image[2].w
 Image[3].x, Image[3].y, Image[3].z, Image[3].w
```

Comment: The title talks about atomics, and the body of the question asks about the value of temp2.  But I don't see the value of temp2 being affected by the atomics.  The effects of the atomics are limited to s in the code snippet.

Comment: Ok you are right. Actually I have shown only a part of the entire code. anyways I am editing tile and code...

Answer (score 1):

We can completely eliminate atomics from this problem since the values of `temp` and `temp2` do not depend on `s`.

```c
__kernel void histogramKernel(__global uint4 *Image,  ....)     
 {                        
     //...                                   
     const uint mask = (uint) (NBINS-1);  //NBINS=256
     uint4 temp = Image[idx];   
     uint4 temp2 = (temp & mask);
     //...
     temp = temp >> 8;
     temp2 = (temp & mask);
     //...
 }
```

Finally the mask is equal to `0x000000FF` so the values of temp are modded by 256 and put into `temp2`.  `temp2` is overwritten on the last line after the value of temp is right shifted by 8 bits.  So we get the value of:

```
temp2 = (Image[idx] / 256) % 256
```

I can't tell from your question what `Image` is initialized to (since there are 4 values and you only seemed to give one).

Comment: These are the 4 values: Image[idx]=idx+100 , so for idx=0, Image[o]=100, idx=1, Image[1]=101, idx=2, Image[2]=102, idx=3, Image[3]=100

Comment: Well what's the value of `Image[0].x`, `Image[0].y`, `Image[0].z`, `Image[0].w`?  It's a `uint4`; every index should have 4 values.

Comment: how many values temp2 will be having? 16?, assuming suitable values can you show me?

Comment: Just substitute each of the values into the function I gave you and you should get the right answers.  The math works individually on each element of the `unit4`.

Comment: In the last equation you wrote, Image[idx] will always have values from 0-255, and thus Image[idx] / 256 , will evaluate to 0 in every case (int/int). Thus Temp2 will always be 0. Where I am wrong?

Comment: Image[idx] may have any 32-bit integer value.  temp2 will have the value 2nd least significant byte of the integer in Image[idx].